# Meaning of "from" in "bank statements or payslips from the last 6 months"

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

UK Immigration [requires](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) "bank statements or payslips **from** the last 6 months" for a Standard Visitor visa. I cannot understand this usage of the word "from".

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/from?q=from%20) give many definitions, the only relevant one in my view is:

> 3.1 Indicating the date at which something was created:
>
> *a document dating from the thirteenth century*

However, it is still ambiguous for me:

1. The statement must be done at any point of time in the last 6 months and its period duration is not specified in the sentence;
2. The statement must cover the last 6 months.

Could you clarify the meaning of such usage?

Comment: Note: 'eg' means 'for example', UKVI frames this as a suggestion only.

Comment: For the record, I disagree with the migration to [travel.se], since the question was about the meaning of an English sentence, and not about the visa requirements. I'm sure that the topic of bank statements has been covered before; I proposed a duplicate but there might be a better one (with a more thorough answer).

Comment: @Gilles, I agree that the way the question as stated belongs to English and should be migrated back. We can devise a canonical question/answer that covers the whole bank statement domain. If it does get migrated back or if it stays here at least one important thing to remember is the UKVI language is vague and ambiguous by design and intent and any evidence outside of a passport and photo is expressed with modal verbs.

Comment: I think this belongs on ELL, not Travel or English